# Do something every click in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, click, uitouch

I am trying to make a square appear on a random CGPoint in Swift every time I click the screen. Below is what I have done with no compiler errors, but once I run the application, I can click or drag to move my "person," but every time I do that, a smaller square does not appear. Any advice or solutions are great. Thank you! by the way, person, a UIImageView is no image but has a viable backgroundColor.`

`

```
    @IBOutlet weak var person: UIImageView!

    var location = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)

    var randomPoint = CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%1000),y:Int(arc4random()%1000))

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first

        location = touch!.locationInView(self.view)

        person.center = location

        for _ in touches {

            let mySquare: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 20,height: 20))

            mySquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()

            mySquare.center = randomPoint

        }

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first

        location = touch!.locationInView(self.view)

        person.center = location

        for _ in touches {

            let mySquare: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 20,height: 20))

            mySquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()

            mySquare.center = randomPoint

        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `mySquare` view onto any view.

```
 self.view.addSubview(mySquare)
```

Comment: Please explain your code a little bit more. This answer is too short for a newbie to understand

Comment: The code is obvious to showed need to add on a parentview. Why down vote it? If can't understand this then shouldn't ask here.

Answer (score 0):

For every touch, you just need create and add(you missed this step) square in touch begin (or touch end), don't do in touch move.

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first

        location = touch!.locationInView(self.view)

        person.center = location

        for _ in touches {

            let mySquare: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 20,height: 20))

            mySquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()

            mySquare.center = randomPoint

            view.addSubview(mySquare) // add square to the view

        }

    }
```